# How can I reach STDIN/STDOUT through a gdbserver session

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging

If I start a normal 'gdb' session, then I can reach `STDIN` and see `STDOUT` directly in the terminal:

```
$ gdb wc
GNU gdb (Gentoo 7.10.1 vanilla) 7.10.1
...
gdb> run
Starting program: /usr/bin/wc 
asdf
      1       1       5
[Inferior 1 (process 28131) exited normally]
gdb> quit
$
```

Can I do the same with a gdbserver???

Here is what I have tried (gdbserver):

```
$ gdbserver /dev/ttyS0 wc
Process wc created; pid = 28156
Listening on port 2345
```

and client:

```
$ gdb
GNU gdb (Gentoo 7.10.1 vanilla) 7.10.1
...
gdb> c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7ddbc40 in _start () from target:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
gdb>
```

But, it seems like `STDIN`/`STDOUT` is not being connected when using the gdbserver.

**How can I run remote debugging over the serial line, and also access `STDIN`/`STDOUT` of the application that I'm debugging over the same serial line??**

Comment: Feature request: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2014-10/msg00004.html

Answer (score 2):

> How can I run remote debugging over the serial line, and also access STDIN/STDOUT of the application that I'm debugging over the same serial line??

You'll need to use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) to multiplex `gdb<->gdbserver` and keyboard->application traffic over a single serial line.